# How to get current learning rate of SGD optimizer in TensorFlow 2.0 when I use tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I want to reduce learning rate in SGD optimizer of tensorflow2.0, I used this line of code:

```
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
            initial_learning_rate=self.parameter['learning_rate'],
            decay_steps=(1000), 
            decay_rate=self.parameter['lr_decay']
        )
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule, momentum=0.9)
```

But I don't know if my learning rate has dropped, how can I get my current learning rate?

Comment: I didn't use model.compile(), but @tf.function
    def train_step(self, x, y):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                y_ = model(x, self.parameter['seqlen_out'])
       
                batch_loss = self.loss_impl(y, y_)
              
            gradients = tape.gradient(batch_loss, self.nks.trainable_variables)
  
            self.opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.nks.trainable_variables))
            return batch_loss

Answer (score 6):

[_decayed_lr](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/96afaa08b282a32870a9ccd20bce42110e4a0adb/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L838) method decays the learning_rate based on the number of iterations as [image: lr_decay] and returns the actual learning rate at that specific iteration. It also casts the returned value to a type that you specify. So, the following code can do the job for you:

```
opt._decayed_lr(tf.float32)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be better to include some description for the code. Like why do you think this should solve the problem or what it does.

Comment: Right. This answer is solving also my problem, because `model.optimizer.learning_rate` doesn't show me the decay. However, I don't really understand how it works

Comment: It didn't work. I used tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.CosineDecay with Adam.

Comment: It also does not work with AdamW (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/experimental/AdamW).

Comment: If you are using an Adam optimiser, the learning rate is kept for each variable. Therefore, a learning rate for all variables (which will decay) may not be kept - as Adam optimiser doesn't use it. ... You may find this so question useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70230021/how-do-we-have-access-to-the-effective-learning-rate-of-adam-tensorflow

Answer (score 5):

@Lisanu's answer worked for me as well. 
Here's why&how that answer works:

[This tensorflow's github webpage](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0e87b6606ef7789fedbd08c0bddc8dc591504d7e/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py) shows the codes for `tf.keras.optimizers`.
If you scroll down, there is a function named `_decayed_lr` which allows users to get the decayed learning rate as a Tensor with dtype=var_dtype.

Therefore, by using `optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32)`, we can get the current decayed learning rate.

If you'd like to print the current decayed learning rate during training in Tensorflow, you can define a custom-callback class and utilize `optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32)`. The example is as follows:

```
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current_decayed_lr = self.model.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32).numpy()
        print("current decayed lr: {:0.7f}".format(current_decayed_lr))
```